# Using Grep -o or Sed/Awk to Grab Snippet from Middle of String

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I am watching log traffic and see regular abuse of the various image search engines, Bing particularly.

Example URL:

```
http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=dagger+genesis+solo&view=detailv2&&&id=C65E811DFE01FB11258D2EB4F516F3DD8F09049C&selectedIndex=4&ccid=ffC0NVO8&simid=608046582336849763&thid=JN.XnLfF7qiZGwjJzTCR6f7ZQ&mode=overlay
```

I want to pull out the search itself, the "dagger genesis solo".

I can

```
grep -o '=*'
```

but that leaves the = sign and everything that follows the search.

I want to grab everything between "search?q=" and the first "&" the end of the last word preceded by a "+".

I could get there in a very long and convoluted way using awk or cut to get strip as much of my string away as possible, and then use specified field separators to put each word in its own column and then print only those columns.  But even that method wouldn't be consistent as the searches can be any length and include just about any character.

I am thinking there is a much easier way though.  Ideas?

My final goal is to strip the search queries and collate them into unique entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
sed 's/^.*search?q=\([^&]*\)&.*/\1/' file
```

What this does is does a non greedy match between the `search?q=` and the `&`

Which outputs

```
dagger+genesis+solo
```

If you want to replace the `+` signs with spaces,

```
sed 's/^.*search?q=\([^&]*\)&.*/\1/;s/+/ /g' file
```

Which outputs

```
dagger genesis solo
```

Comment: The second option works perfectly as a one stop option instead of me needing to take care of the +'s as a post-action.  Could you kindly explain how the brackets inside the parenthesis works with sed?

Comment: The `[^&]` means match a single character that is not the ampersand. The way to match a character is `[]`, and the `^` is the negation operator. The `*` means match any number of occurrences of the previous character. Also the second option is just the first option combined with an additional command to substitute the `+` signs, namely `s/+/ /g`

Answer (score 4):

If your system's `grep` supports PCRE-mode, you could use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (zero length assertions) to select characters *between* `search?q=` and `&`

```
grep -Po '(?<=search\?q=).+?(?=&)'
```

Using the non-greedy modifier `?` in between makes the match stop at the first `&`.

Comment: That works as I originally wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([^=&]*.\)\{2\}&.*/\1/' <<""
http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=dagger+genesis+solo&view=detailv2&&&id=C65E811DFE01FB11258D2EB4F516F3DD8F09049C&selectedIndex=4&ccid=ffC0NVO8&simid=
```

When an occurrence count is specified for a back-referenced match, `sed` should reference only the specified match. So in the above example the reference returns only

```
dagger+genesis+solo
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grep look-behind and look-ahead assertions:

```
grep -oP "\=\K.*(?=\&view)"
```

Here,

```
\K          ==>  zero-width look-behind assertion
(?=\&view)  ==>  zero-width look-ahead assertion
```

Hence, only the part in-between `\=` and `&view` i.e. `.*` is printed.